# Django static files not served on Heroku production

Tags: django, heroku

I have a django web site deployed to Heroku. None of the static or media files are loading when I switch out of debug mode. I have a media folder with images and successfully ran collectstatic and have a static folder with many files. Here is the relevant code:

```
# settings.py
PROJECT_ROOT = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_DIR = 'media'
MEDIA_ROOT = join(PROJECT_ROOT, MEDIA_DIR)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIR = 'static'
STATIC_ROOT = join(PROJECT_ROOT, STATIC_DIR)

# wsgi.py
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "sitemoz.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Comment: What is your `PROJECT_ROOT` ?

Comment: It is PROJECT_ROOT = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))

Comment: Okay your static and media files are in your project package folder... Did you tried with `PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` ?

Comment: The two static folders (static and media) are in the root of the project. I just tried switching the PROJECT_ROOT and it is giving the same error.

Comment: No way. `dirname(dirname(abspath(file)))` resolves `myproject` where settings.py and other files along with it ?

Comment: The tree looks like this:
/media
/sitemoz
  settings.py
/static

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145200/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-casey).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the static root folder so your setup will work. The reason for this you can't use `Static  Folder` and `STATIC_ROOT` in the same folder.